# urllib2.urlopen throws 404 exception for urls that browser opens

Tags: python, http, exception, debugging, urllib2

The following url (and others like it) can be opened in a browser but causes urllib2.urlopen to throw a 404 exception: http://store.ovi.com/#/applications?categoryId=20&fragment=1&page=1

geturl() returns the same url (no redirect). The headers are copied and pasted from firebug. I tried passing in the headers as a dictionary to Request, but got the same result.  wget opens the url in the console but not from the script.

**the code:**

source_url = 'http://store.ovi.com/#/applications?categoryId=20&fragment=1&page=2'
try:

```
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
    hdrs = [('Host','store.ovi.com'),('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US;rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073021 Firefox/3.0.13 AppEngine-Google;(+http://code.google.com/appengine)'),('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),('Accept-Language','en-us,en;q=0.5'),('Accept-Encoding','gzip,deflate'),('Accept-Charset','ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'),('Keep-Alive','115'),('Connection','keep-alive'),('Cookie','JNPRSESSID=4u4devdrt7eb6e0qem3gin47i2; s_cc=true; undefined_s=First%20Visit; s_nr=1282817443274; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; view=Grid; menu=menuOpen; OVI_DEVICE=b5130'),('Cache-Control','max-age=0')]
ree = urllib2.Request(source_url)
    ree.addheaders = hdrs
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    htmlSource = opener.open(ree).read()
```

except urllib2.HTTPError, e:

```
    print e.code  
    print e.msg
    print e.headers
```

**The error output:**
404
Not Found
Date: Sat, 28 Aug 2010 00:36:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.2
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=7, max=333
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

What, if anything, am I doing incorrectly?  Is this a bug? And if so, is there a workaround?  Thanks!

Comment: the fragment in the url seems to be messing things up

Answer (score 3):

Given a URL like:

```
http://store.ovi.com/#/applications?categoryId=20&fragment=1&page=2
```

The bit that browsers fetch is just:

```
http://store.ovi.com/
```

Everything to the right of that is a ‘fragment identifier’, which is not passed to the server at all (evidently, if you try, it will get confused). Instead, the HTML returned for the `/` URL will include a load of JavaScript that reads the `#...` data at the client side and fills in the page content using a bunch of `XMLHttpRequest`s.

Webapps implemented like this are a big old pain to scrape, because you can't just take the HTML content of the main page. Instead you have to either analyse the script to find out where it gets the actual data from, or you have to hook up a real browser in order to execute all the scripts and see what document objects you're left with. They're also typically bad for accessibility and SEO.

Luckily for you this site appears to be putting something in the fragment that's also a valid path. So it looks like you can get the dynamic page data from the URL:

```
http://store.ovi.com/applications?categoryId=20&fragment=1&page=1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Opening the url using wget() from the console works with no problem.  Why does wget seem to pass the fragment identifier successfully, while urlib2 doesn't?

Thanks.

Comment: `wget` doesn't pass the fragment identifier, it cuts it off the URL before using it. It's kind of a bug if `urllib2` doesn't.